# std::vector not retaining data?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have this code:

```
void BaseOBJ::update(BaseOBJ* surround[3][3])
{
    forces[0]->Apply(); //in place of for loop
    cout << forces[0]->GetStrength() << endl; //forces is an std::vector of Force*
}
```

void BaseOBJ::AddForce(float str, int newdir, int lifet, float lifelength)
{

```
Force newforce;
newforce.Init(draw, str, newdir, lifet, lifelength);
forces.insert(forces.end(), &newforce);
cout << forces[0]->GetStrength();
```

}

Now, when I call AddForce and make an infinite force with a strength of one, it cout's 1. But when update is called, it just outputs 0, as if the force were no longer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing a pointer to force in your vector but the force is function local.

You must use `new` to create in on the heap.

```
Force* f = new Force;
forces.push_back(f);
```

Comment: +1 And do not forget to call delete on each element of the vector when exiting.

Comment: @Chris: Don't forget to call `delete`. Even better - use `boost::ptr_vector` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your Force with new:

```
Force *newforce = new Force;
newforce->Init(draw, str, newdir, lifet, lifelength);
forces.insert(forces.end(), newforce); // or: forces.push_back(force);
```

What happens with your code is that your object remains on the stack, after you leave the function and do something else, it gets overwritten.

Why a vector of pointers? Probably you want a vector of Force, not Force*. You would also have to delete all elements of your vector before you throw it away!